# Orchard CMS: Upgrade from 1.9 to 1.10.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.9

I have a version 1.9 of Orchard and need to upgrade to the newest version, in this case 1.10.2. 
But while following the steps described in their official post:
[Orchard Update Link](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Upgrading-a-site-to-a-new-version-of-Orchard/)
Where I am following the - Upgrading a Running Instance of Orchard to a New Version.

I get an error on one of the modules that I have already installed on the previous version:

The type or namespace name 'Contrib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)       c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f429b97c\ac3091ab\App_Web_lfacz42g.0.cs

The module that throws the error: Contrib.Mod.ChangePassword

Comment: Hi, in 1.10.2 there is no need for this module. It is included in core of Orchard.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the .Net Framework to 4.5.2 in your modules and themes.

The important steps that are needed to be followed for upgrading orchard cms are:

1. First get the latest orchard cms code repos(1.10.2)
2. Add your custom modules and themes from the previous orchard cms project(sometimes tests)
3. Upgrade the dot net framework in your added custom modules and themes to Dot net 4.5.2.